# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to49} \frac{x-49}{\sqrt{x}-7}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 49} \frac{x-49}{\sqrt{x}-7}$

I'm guessing the answer is 7 but again that is only a guess. I don't know how to solve this type of problem.

Please help.

Comment: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x \to 49} \frac {x - 49}{\sqrt x - 7} = \lim_{x \to 49} \frac {(\sqrt x + 7)(\sqrt x - 7)}{\sqrt x - 7} = \lim_{x \to 49} (\sqrt x + 7) = 14
$$

Comment: so I'm going to simplify $x-49$ and turn it into $\sqrt{x}-7$ for which it will cancel out with the denominator. This helps a lot!!

Comment: @JohnBeal, yes, that's pretty typical thing to do in this kind of problems.

Answer (score 10):

Since both numerator and denominator go to $0$, you can apply [L'Hospital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Since the answer hasd been given, I guess it is safe to demonstrate:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to49}\frac{x-49}{\sqrt{x}-7}
&=\lim_{x\to49}\frac{1}{\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to49}2\sqrt{x}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Wow, this is rather elegant here!

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  let $x=y^2$, now it may be easier to find a common factor.

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to49}\frac{x-49}{\sqrt{x}-7}=\lim_{x\to49}\frac{x-49}{\sqrt{x}-7}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}+7}{\sqrt{x}+7}=\lim_{x\to49}\frac{(x-49)(\sqrt{x}+7)}{x-49}=\lim_{x\to49}(\sqrt{x}+7)=14$.

(Here I am multiplying the top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator, which is a common way to find limits of the form $0/0$ involving square roots.  However, I prefer Kaster's method myself.)

Comment: Multiplying the numerator and the denominator by the same thing is a useful tool. However, this is similar to Kaster's answer, so a bit of explanation would probably be good to differentiate the answers.

Comment: I prefer Kaster's method myself, but I posted this answer to illustrate that a common method to find limits of the form $0/0$ involving square roots is to multiply by the conjugate (in this case, of the denominator) on the top and bottom.  (Some students seem to prefer this way of doing it.)

Comment: I am not saying that your answer is a duplicate of Kaster's, nor am I saying that it is not good. However, it would be nice to include a bit of description in the answer saying what exactly you are doing, in order to better differentiate your answer from Kaster's.

Comment: @robjohn I agree with you, and I added some explanatory remarks - thanks.